# Cors enabled on server, POST works, DELETE doesn't

Tags: reactjs, rest, redux

I'm trying to learn redux, and so I'm creating a small site that uses a third party API to search and add movies to my own database, where I then use redux and react to display them. The point is to keep track of movie suggestions people give me, and when I watch them I remove them from the list.

I made this before in purely react, but I'm recreating it to learn redux.

The thing is, in my react-only version, I use this on a button click to delete and it works fine:

```
deleteThisMovie = () => {
  this.props.closeModal();

  this.props.toastAlert(`${this.props.title} successfully removed.`, 'success');

  api.deleteMovie(this.props.id)
  .then(this.props.updateMovies);
}
```

Here is the API code:

```
deleteMovie = (movieId) => (
  superagent
  .delete(`${API_HOST}/movies/${movieId}`)
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
)
```

This deletes just fine.

=======================

In my react/redux version, this is my action:

```
function removeMovieFromDB(movieID) {
  const request = superagent.delete(`${API_HOST}/movies/${movieID}`);
  return request;
}

export function removeMovieAndRefresh(movieID) {
  return dispatch => (
    removeMovieFromDB(movieID).then((res) => {
        dispatch(fetchMovies());
        return res;
    })
);
```

}

And in my component it's called like this:

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => this.removeMovie(apiID)}>
Remove
</button>
```

And that function is this:

```
removeMovie = (movieID) => {
    this.props.removeMovieAndRefresh(movieID);
    this.closeModal();
}
```

In this version, when I click the button, I get this error:

> Failed to load {host_goes_here}/movies/12219: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

My relevant server code is this:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

and the mongoDB controller delete code:

```
moviesController.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Movie.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Movie removed successfully.');
  })
  .then(() => res.status(204).end());
});
```

Any idea what's going on with my redux delete? Am I missing something? I tried using axios as well but that didn't work. I also tried just a basic fetch with method: 'DELETE'. That didn't work either. But when I use my react only version with the same server, it deletes without issue.

Comment: I don't know if the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` for `DELETE` is enabled by default with the `cors` module, but might want to check on that. Or that you need to add `.options` route before your `.delete`

Comment: But then how come it works with my react only version, and not with my react-redux version?

Comment: If your server returns 503 and not 4xx / 2xx it indicates a server error. Maybe you have another error and the missing CORS headers are just a side-effect of the crash?

Comment: ^What he asked. Do you have a log on the server when it errors out? Maybe change that `if (err) throw err` to something like `if (err) { console.error(err); throw err; }` to get the log if it doesn't initially logging out the error.

Comment: My errors are now this:

    
    ====    DELETE {host_here}/movies/12219 503 (Service Unavailable)

then the error I posted above

and then this:

    ====    Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.


Followed by a warning:

    ====    Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response {host_here}/movies/12219 ...


Then I have to restart my server. But I can't imagine why it's crashing with redux but not with react